# styled lettered lists in epub

Tags: html, css, epub

In an epub, I would like to style a single lettered list in this manner:

> ```
> (a) Some text goes here.
> (b) More text here.
> (c) This line is longer. It goes on and on. And on some more. And then it
>     keeps going until it wraps.
> (d) Another long line. This one will wrap too, once it gets to be long
>     enough. You get the idea. The text should always line up while the
>     list letters hang.
> ```

The following code will do what I want on a per-list basis:

```
ol.alpha_list { 
  counter-reset: item;

}

ol.alpha_list > li {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}

ol.alpha_list li:before {
  counter-increment: item;
  content:"(" counter(item, lower-alpha) ") ";
  position: absolute;
  left: -1.4em;
}
```

But this doesn't render correctly in my epub file. It comes out like this:

> ```
> (a) Some text goes here.
> (b) More text here.
> (c) This line is longer. It goes on and on. And on some more. And then it
> keeps going until it wraps.
> (d) Another long line. This one will wrap too, once it gets to be long
> enough. You get the idea. The text should always line up while the
> list letters hang.
> ```

Is there any way to make it work like the first example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding "list-style-position: outside;" and  "margin-left: 2em;" in the li css.

```
ol.alpha_list { 
  counter-reset: item;

}

ol.alpha_list > li {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    list-style-position: outside;
    margin-left: 2em;
}

ol.alpha_list li:before {
  counter-increment: item;
  content:"(" counter(item, lower-alpha) ") ";
  position: absolute;
  left: -1.4em;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for trying, but that didn't work. I'm editing the book in Calibre, and it renders correctly (so did my original CSS), but it doesn't render correctly in Marvin on my iPhone. iBooks seems to work, though, which is weird because I thought iBooks and Marvin would use the same HTML renderer.

Comment: Whoops! Marvin has a setting to "Switch to Publisher's formatting", and that did the trick. It renders correctly now in Marvin when I do this. Thanks again!